# How to map cubic pixels to a 2d grid maintaining distance relationships

Tags: combinations, coordinate-systems, cubics

I have only basic math understanding, so please excuse any lack of clarity.

I want to crochet an afghan using all the possible 3-color combinations of 6 yarns. Or maybe that's ridiculously too many, I can't tell. The inspiration for this is this blanket: [blanket with 2 color combos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi5wD.jpg) which has all the 2-color combinations of 10 yarns. Obviously, there will be many more 3-color combinations of 6 yarns.

It may be relevant how this is acheived, which is by holding multiple strands of fine yarn together and using them as one yarn. This allows the possibility of the gradient being more gradual too - for example by using 5 strands instead of 3, but only 3 colors!

Here are my thoughts:
Because it's a 3-color combination, one option is to simply represent it as a cube, with each axis representing a color gradient (so x might run from red through gray to green, y from purple through gray to yellow, z from blue through gray to orange). This also prevents "mixing" of the opposite colors, which might be beneficial aesthetically. Assuming I like that, how do I then map each of those cubic coordinates onto a 2d grid? The other inspiration for this is the game I Love Hue Too, specifically this gameboard: [gameboard with color gradient on diamond/hex grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVLQe.jpg) and I'm wondering if a simple hex grid would give a more aesthetic gradient, or something like this made of diamonds.

So the simple question is how to map a cube onto a hex (or other simple) grid and roughly preserve the distance relationships from the cube. Other thoughts are welcome!

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to swat your fly with a sledgehammer called [Netto's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netto%27s_theorem): There's no way to map a cube into a square that preserves the structure in a continuous way. That's not to say there aren't good ways to map the $216$ different color sequences into a grid. But I wouldn't go through the cube.

Comment: Ok, and there's also not a good way to map a cube into a hexagon that preserves the structure either . . . Or even roughly does? I guess mathematics isn't interested usually in approximating to the same degree that art is :) Like, I'm sort of thinking that the "cross shape" that you can use to fold up into a cube from flat paper is kind of sort of hexagon shaped, except with one long tail . . . Well, and actually octagonal. Ok, so not at all hexagonal! Lol!

Comment: If you only want combinations, there are just $20$: $\binom{6}{3} = \frac{6!}{3!3!} = \frac{720}{36} = 20$. We can enumerate them: ABC, ABD, ABE, ABF, ACD, ACE, ACF, ADE, ADF, AEF, BCD, BCE, BCF, BDE, BDF, BEF, CDE, CDF, CEF, DEF. That fits nicely into a $4$-by-$5$ array. I'm curious enough to spend some time thinking about an elegant arrangement.

Comment: Here's an approach using [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve): https://allrgb.com/hilbert and https://karldray.com/colorspace.html

Comment: Yes, but also combinations with repetition! So that increases it . . . AAA AAB AAC AAD AAE AAF BBA BBB BBC BBD BBE BBF CCA CCB CCC CCD CCE CCF DDA DDB DDC DDD DDE DDF EEA EEB EEC EED EEE EEF FFA FFB FFC FFD FFE FFF.  So that's 46 total :)

Comment: And a parameter I forgot to mention is that the shapes all must be the same, and preferably regular. So isoceles triangles would work, or diamonds (two isoceles triangles together) or hexagons.

Comment: And thank you for the space-fitting curves, that's approaching what I'm looking for, for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible arrangement and coloring. Since there are $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ different combinations of three colors selected out of six total, this design is based on a flattening of the $20$-sided regular polyhedron, the icosahedron. The icosahedron usually looks like this (a d$20$, if you've gamed before):

[image]

Flattened out, it can be arranged like this:

[image]

There are $19$ triangles shown; the $20$th and last side is represented by the entire outside, and is labeled orange/green/purple here. Each of the other regions is labeled with their three colors. This design has the property that any two adjacent sides share two colors, while diametrically opposite sides share no colors. All triangles that share two colors are furthermore either adjacent or both border the same triangle (I believe).

I haven't sat down and figured out how many such arrangements there are. I also don't expect anyone to actually use these colors; the combinations look a little gruesome. But a simple substitution will work. :-)

Comment: That's awesome, thank you for putting in the effort! Honestly it's pretty intriguing, though I agree that the combinations aren't all pretty. Well, they don't seem pretty, but it worked pretty well in the squares blanket, even when I thought it wouldn't.

Comment: So just to see if I understand this, there are 20 non-repeating combinations, 46 repeating. Because it's a factorial, if I wanted to add more strands it would be multiplied again . . . So if I wanted 4 strands it would be 184 combinations allowing repeats? 5 strands would be 920?? But I got 462 for 6 strands (choose 6 of 6, repeats allowed) using the formula I found at https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html . . .

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Posting as an answer because I think I have guessed what you are trying to say.

In the picture there are $10 \times 10 = 100$ squares. You describe those as the "two color combinations of $10$ yarns" but that's not the right mathematical language. It probably represents all the pairs $(x,y)$ where each of $x$ and $y$ is one of the colors of yarn (they can be the same color). In this count, (red, blue) is not the same as (blue, red).

If that's what you mean then with three combinations of $6$ yarns there will be $6 \times 6 \times 6 = 216$ possibilities. That's only about twice $100$. The nearest you could get to a square pattern would be $12$ by $18$.

I haven't thought about arranging the $216$ combinations as hexagons or parallelograms in a hex grid. You could work on that by experimenting with [hex grid graph paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex%20grid%20graph%20paper%20printable&client=ubuntu&hs=ihO&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALiCzsbkyuz_V6T--WBuYuDGiGiLis2U8A%3A1658445335134&ei=F97ZYuPCB6KJptQP6NmQqAI&ved=0ahUKEwijqtGojov5AhWihIkEHegsBCUQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=hex%20grid%20graph%20paper%20printable).

Good luck with the aesthetics. I don't think there's mathematics for that.

Comment: $6 \times 6 \times 6 = 216$, not $108$. Or did you mean something else? (Least oblong rectangle would be $12 \times 18$.)

Comment: @BrianTung Oops! Thanks. Fixed (you could have edited.)

Comment: I could have. I'm very tentative about that, as some people don't like it. But I'll keep that in mind for you. :-)

Comment: That's right, except the only thing I don't like about that blanket is that it does not treat x=1, y=2 the same as x=2, y=1. I would prefer each unique combination only appear once, and that's what I'm hoping to achieve here. That's combinations, not permutations, right? Specifically combinations with repetition.

Comment: And thank you for the link to the hex grid graph paper - I drew some myself but it was tedious!